# How to batch FFT in C

Tags: c, fftw

I am trying to do a batch FFT on 50 images using the following snippet:

```
pix3 = n*pix1*pix2;
fftwf_complex *in2, *f2h; //input for FFT2
in2 = (fftwf_complex*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * pix3);
f2h = (fftwf_complex*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * pix3);

for (i = 0; i < pix3; i++)
{
in2[i][0] = ref20[i]; //ref20 is an array of real values 
in2[i][1] = 0;
}    

for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  plan_forward2 = fftwf_plan_dft_2d (pix1, pix2, in2, f2h, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftwf_execute (plan_forward2);
  in2 += pix1*pix2;
  f2h += pix1*pix2;
}
```

However, I am only able to get the FFT of the 1st image (i.e. first pix1*pix2 elements). Any suggestions on how to get this right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may need to show the code in between the initial memory allocation and the for loop, i.e. the part that actually loads the images into in2.

Comment: after mem allocation, I am just reading the data (size=pix3) from a text file and then converting my variable to a complex type (in2)

Answer (score 2):

You should read [the manual 4.6 New-array Execute Functions](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/New_002darray-Execute-Functions.html#New_002darray-Execute-Functions) carefully

You only need to create the plan once outside the loop, and then use it as:

```
fftwf_execute_dft(plan_forward2, in2, f2h);
```

Comment: The "advanced" interface allows batches, that's what I am using... I wonder if just reusing the same plan would have the same speed with less memory consumption.